# Restoring cassandra node from data, digest, index and filter files

Tags: ubuntu, migration, cql, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

I've been thrown headfirst into the whole Cassandra world with a task to migrate an 8 node cluster running an ancient version of Cassandra (1.0.8) to a new cluster running 2.1.13.. I did a bunch of googling but wasn't able to find anything conclusive on how to manage this migration so rather than spend my time googling further and getting frustrated over the lack of good answers to my question I decided to jump into it and booted up a node for my new cluster.

With my new node I proceeded to to a DESC KEYSPACE [keyspace] on my old node and with a bit of modifications to the output from there (it made columnfamilies rather than tables and some things were defined in other ways than the newer CQL wants it) I was able to create the desired tables on my new node.

I then proceeded to scp the content of /raid0/cassandra/data/[keyspace] to my new node at /raid0/cassandra/data/[keyspace] and doing so I figured I would be able to run nodetool repair or nodetool refresh, or some other nice nodetool command in order to make it rebuild everything from the data folder, however it seems that what I'm trying isn't working since nothing is getting into my tables, they still just return 0 when I run SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [table]; in the cqlsh.

Anyone able to help me figure out how I can make the data import properly into the keyspace on my new node?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from 1.0 to 2.1 is a big step - operationally, you're probably going to be much happier once it's done, but it's not going to be a super easy process.

First thing to note: snapshots in Cassandra are your friend. They're hard links, they take mere seconds, and they will really help you roll back if something bad happens. Before you do anything, take a snapshot on each node.

Now, to upgrade from 1.0 to 2.1, you're actually going to need to do a bunch of upgrades:

1.0 -> 1.1

1.1 -> 1.2

1.2 -> 2.0

2.0 -> 2.1

Sound miserable? It probably will be. Each version of cassandra will have a list of 'gotchas' for upgrading:

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-1.0/NEWS.txt

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-1.1/NEWS.txt

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-1.2/NEWS.txt

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.0/NEWS.txt

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/NEWS.txt

If I were in your shoes (and I have been in the past), I'd try to mentally decide if upgrade-in-place or export-data-and-reimport is easier. If you've got a few hundred gigs of data, it's probably small enough to export and re-import (which you'll probably need to do manually with your favorite programming language).

If you have a reasonably significant amount of data, simply upgrade one node at a time, one version at a time. At each major version, run upgradesstables. Once all sstables are upgraded, upgrade to the next major version.

In the past when I've needed to do this with smaller data sets, I did it with a dedicated batch machine:

- I attached a large amount of storage
- For each version in cassandra-1.1, 1.2, 2.0, 2.1:
- For each node in the cluster:
- Copy the data to that node (1 node's worth of data at a time)
- Run upgradesstables
- Copy the data off to a holding location

At the end of the process, you have all the sstables for 2.1 - pretty straight forward to then copy the data files to a 2.1 cluster, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer, Jeff! This gives me at least a very specific action plan to go through in order to reach the goals!